# Changing 3 column to 1 and taking a count of its customers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this following that I need to roll to "Chinese" only and take a count of all these 3 Chinese languages:

[image]

so my desired output is one row as follows:

Chinese as PrimaryLanguage and 900 as Total count. The rest of the list contains a lot of other languages that I don't need to roll.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always show what you have tried..

Comment: Strip off everything after a hyphen?? `case when primaryLanguage like 'Chinese%' then 'Chinese' else primaryLanguage end`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple query :

```
select 'Chinese' as PrimaryLanguage, #Count from (
    select count(*) as #Count from table1
    where language in ('Chinese', 'Chinese-Cantonese', 'Chinese-Mandarin')
) as T
```

Comment: This is what exactly I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when language in ('Chinese', 'Chinese-Cantonese', 'Chinese-Mandarin')
             then 'Chinese' else language
        end) as language,
       count(*)
from t
group by  (case when language in ('Chinese', 'Chinese-Cantonese', 'Chinese-Mandarin')
                then 'Chinese' else language
           end)
```

If you want all Chinese languages, you can change the conditions to `language like 'Chinese%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 'Chinese', sum([#Count]) from MY_TABLE where primaryLanguage like '%Chinese%'
```